# Unable to connect to the NBAndroid because of Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: netbeans, plugins, netbeans-plugins

I have just installed NetBeans 8.0.2, and I want to install NBAndroid plugin. I have the link which is http://nbandroid.org/release81/updates/updates.xml 
when I click to update and install it it gives me a message saying "Unable to connect to the NBAndroid because of Unexpected end of file from server" I have tried many ways to solve it but none of them worked. Help please

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the problem of plugin here is the solution by gitHub for Netbeans 8.1 and Netbeans 8.2 https://github.com/NBANDROIDTEAM/NBANDROID-V2
usi